# Как найти значения свойства объекта?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, filter

Есть объект с героями.У каждого героя есть ключ movies - это массив с фильмами, где участвовал данный герой. Мне необходимо найти всех героев, у которых в movies есть значение "Thor". Как это можно реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Язык программирования то хоть какой?

Comment: Язык JavaScript

Comment: Может массив героев?

Comment: Пожалуйста, в будущем не постите код картинкой, публикуйте текстовый вариант, чтобы отвечающим было легче писать и тестировать ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.filter(item => {
  return item.movies.includes('Thor')
})
```